# Location of text in table cells

Tags: tables, align

I'm trying to make a test for my students and make a table for multiple choice answers. it looks  like this right now. below is my code.

[image]

```
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{4}
\begin{table}[hbtp!]
    \begin{tabular}{|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|N}
    \hline
        1. &2.  &3. &4. &5. &6. &7. &8. &9. \\
        \hline
         10. & & & & & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\egroup
```

I am trying to put the numbers in the top left corners of the boxes. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) with your table. Without it  we don't know, how `M` column type is defined, which document class you use etc

Answer (score 2):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tabcolsep2pt
 \begin{tabular}{|p{1.4cm}|p{1.4cm}|}\hline
 1. & 2. \\[\dimexpr1.4cm-10pt]\hline
 10. &  \\[\dimexpr1.4cm-10pt]\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: amazing, thank you